# How can you use a abstract method in java without defining it?

Tags: java, android

In android List interface,

I have

```
private List<Contact> contacts;
```

Also there is,

```
Contact contact = contacts.get(position);
```

But get is a abstract method defined in List interface.

So how is this possible to write ?

*FULL CODE :*

```
public class ListViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(new ContactsAdapter(this));
    }

    class ContactsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact> {
        private List<Contact> contacts;

        public ContactsAdapter(Context context) {
            super(context, -1);
            this.contacts = MockDataGenerator.getMockContacts(1000);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView,
                            @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder viewHolder;

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext())
                        .inflate(R.layout.contact_item, parent, false);

                viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            } else {
                viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            Contact contact = contacts.get(position);

            viewHolder.nameTextView.setText(contact.getName());
            viewHolder.mobileTextView.setText(contact.getMobile());
            viewHolder.landlineTextView.setText(contact.getLandline());

            return convertView;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return this.contacts.size();
        }

        class ViewHolder {
            private TextView nameTextView;
            private TextView mobileTextView;
            private TextView landlineTextView;

            public ViewHolder(@NonNull View view) {
                this.nameTextView = (TextView)view
                        .findViewById(R.id.name_text_view);
                this.mobileTextView = (TextView)view
                        .findViewById(R.id.mobile_text_view);
                this.landlineTextView = (TextView)view
                        .findViewById(R.id.landline_text_view);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MockContacts generator :

```
public static List<Contact> getMockContacts(int length) {
    ArrayList<Contact> mockContacts = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        mockContacts.add(getMockContact());
    }
    return mockContacts;
}
```

Comment: have you passed a number to `get`? like `contacts.get(2)`? the position is the index of the object in the list.

Comment: All interface methods are abstract (on the interface).  But if you're invoking a method on an object, then that object perforce has a concrete class, with definitions for all abstract methods inherited from superclasses and implemented interfaces.  The method implementation associated with the object's class is invoked.

Comment: My question is since contacts is a List , how can you use contacts.get(position) where i have not implemented get method

Comment: Just to add, I believe default implementations were added in java 8.... so technically speaking, an interface can provide a default implementation. Not that it's an answer to your specific question, but generally related to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MockDataGenerator.getMockContacts(1000)` is returning an instance of a concrete type that extends `List<T>` (and therefore must define an implementation for `get()`). When you call `contacts.get(position)`, this is a virtual method call, and the JVM will use the implementation provided by the type returned by `MockDataGenerator.getMockContacts(1000)`.

Comment: But the return type of getMockContacts() is List<Contact> - but it generates ArrayList - which confuses me. If it was ArrayList - which has an actual implementation that would make sense

Comment: I recommend reading up on polymorphism a bit. That is what enables it (and it's a good thing).

Answer (score 0):

Your `contact` list is initialized in the constructor:

```
public ContactsAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, -1);
    this.contacts = MockDataGenerator.getMockContacts(1000);
}
```

So here I would assume your `MockDataGenerator` is generating a list of a thousand **mock** contacts

Comment: public static List<Contact> getMockContacts(int length) {
        ArrayList<Contact> mockContacts = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            mockContacts.add(getMockContact());
        }
        return mockContacts;
    }

Comment: My question is since contacts is a List , how can you use contacts.get(position) where i have not implemented get method

Comment: `List` is an interface which defines *what methods your object needs to have*, but it does not tell you what implementation will be used. However, when you're invoking `getMockContacts` - that implementation creates an instance of `ArrayList`.

Comment: @raxx Because `contacts` has an actual implementation class, `ArrayList`, which _does_ implement `get`.

Answer (score 0):

It returns the abstract method of the List interface, because the interface defines the method. But it doesn't mean that at run time (when your program is performed) it is executed exactly this method. Instead, `List<Contact> contacts`;` refers any object which class imports this exact interface. For example, there are two widely used List realizations: ArrayList and LinkedList. Both of them implement the List interface and provide their own implementations of it's methods. The get(i) is one of these methods. Let me show you in practice:

```
public class Example {
private static List<String> stringList = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    initList();

    final String s = stringList.get(0);
}

public static void initList() {
    stringList = new ArrayList<>();
    stringList.add("OneString");
    stringList.add("SecondString");
}
```

}

Here `stringList.get(0)` also returns the abstract method get. But at run time it invokes the method of ArrayList, because ArrayList is the type of the object and ArrayList overrides this method.